# Bash script generated command valid on console but not in script

Tags: bash, avconv

Following puzzle: I have written a bash script with the simple
task of extracting picture-less mp3 from mp4 files. The idea of this first draft is to just use

```
avconv -i input.mp4 output.mp3
```

which works fine on the console.

```
#!/bin/bash
# "extract_mp3_from_mp4.sh test.mp4 test.mp3"

if [ $# == 0 ]; then
        echo -e "Extracts mp3 from mp4 video.\nUsage: $0 src_mp4 [target_mp3=src_mp4.mp3];"
        exit 0;
fi;

file_in=$1;
file_out=$2;
if [ -z $file_out ]; then file_out="${file_in}.mp3"; fi;

echo "Attempting to extract '${file_in}' to '${file_out}'";

cmd="avconv -i ${file_in} ${file_out};";
echo "Casting command: ${cmd}";

exit `$cmd`;
```

Consider the call

```
./extract_mp3_from_mp4.sh test.mp4 test.mp3
```

generating the command

```
avconv -i test.mp4 test.mp3;
```

What baffles me is this: The command created by the script is
absolutely valid. If I copy it from the output generated by
the *echo "Casting command: ..."* right into the console the
command works as expected. However when used in the script
(*exit `$cmd`*) avconv returns

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'test.mp3;
```

How can that be?

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon from the string that you build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon:

```
cmd="avconv -i ${file_in} ${file_out};";
```

should be

```
cmd="avconv -i ${file_in} ${file_out}";
```

I basically recommend NOT using semicolons in BASH scripts, as this happens quite often

Comment: Ooookay... trying it out I instantly see the wisdom of your words as my issue is solved. Thank you very much! :-) Is it impossible then to use several commands in one `..`? At any rate... carefully reading the avconv error message again it _does_ appear that the program has added the ';' to the output file name and was overtasked finding a codec for ".mp3;" output.

Comment: In scripts, the line breaks work good enough. In one-liners make sure, you have a blank **before** and **after** the `;`

Comment: The `;` being added to the last argument is exactly the problem - leaving a blank will most often help